# Is it possible to write ColdFusion statement within Javascript?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am new to CF, just want to know is it possible to call CF statement within Javascript/JQuery? Is the below statement is valid or not, I want to assign a value to the CF variable in JS?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#btn-cancel").on("click", function(){
                unChkEvent=0;

                <cfif IsDefined("arguments.intAssetID")>
                    <cfset session.app.assetID = 0 >
                </cfif>  
            });
</script>
```

I have no issue in the below statement. Only issue is in `<cfset>`. Could you explain why?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#btn-cancel").on("click", function(){
                    unChkEvent=0;

                    <cfif IsDefined("arguments.intAssetID")>
                        alert('Argument defined');
                    <cfelse>
                        alert('Argument NOT defined');    
                    </cfif>  
                });
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes and no.  The cfif is ok, the cfset is not.

Comment: So, how to change the CF variable value on click of a button in JS based on a condition? Only I have use Ajax call to a CF function.

Comment: By submitting an http request back to the server, either via ajax or a regular form submit.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417317/can-i-use-coldfusion-tags-in-javascript/35419507#35419507 . Since the basic question was already asked an answered, voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: But <cfif> is working fine. Why we have issue in only <cfset>. Either both should not work?

Comment: No, it is *not* working. At least not the way you are thinking. Read the link above. It explains why.